# Custom Outlook form that saves data to SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development, client-object-model, sharepoint-rest-api, outlook

My requirement:

A form with check-boxes, labels and buttons inside a outlook email that can take input from the recipient of the email and when submit button is hit should save data to SharePoint

Note: I don't have Info Path designer installed and would like to explore other options